# What is definition of module?

Tags: module, programming-languages

Is there strict definition what a module is (in programming languages)? What minimal properties are required? I.e. on what grounds one may claim that given programming language has modules or not?

Is there any classification of module features so that one implementation is stronger/better than the other?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is any kind of 'official module definition'. what i think is: 
modules are about separation of interests. that usually includes separation on files level but much more important are namespaces. when i write my code i don't want to bother about other programmers except module names. and different languages fail at different level of module management.

- javascript has no modules at all. there is one global namespace people started to use anonymous functions and invent different ways of combining different libraries without polluting the namespace.
- i don't know c++ much but AFAIK it allows you to declare classes but there isn't any way to bundle many classes into something bigger so if you try to link someone's library with your code you may have linkage errors.
- java has packages and naming conventions (from domain name) so it's rather easy to keep separated namespaces (although it's not enforced by the language) but transitive dependencies sucks as on your dependency tree there can't be two same modules with different versions

so you have to pick/create your own definition of a module